# Pushout of Nisnevich sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, limits-and-colimits, grothendieck-topology, simplicial-presheaves

Let us consider the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$ over a field $k$ and take the following open embeddings
$$j_{\epsilon}\colon \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,\infty\} \to \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\epsilon\}$$
for $\epsilon \in \{0,\infty\}$.
Since $\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,\infty\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A^1}\setminus \{0\}$ we can fix a closed embedding
$$i\colon \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0, \infty\}\to \mathbb{A}^2$$
and consider the induced maps:
$$(i,j_{\epsilon})\colon \mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,\infty\}\to\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\epsilon\}\times \mathbb{A}^2.$$
In ``$\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory of schemes'' by Morel and Voevodsky I've read that the pushout of the diagram
$$\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0\}\times \mathbb{A}^2\leftarrow\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,\infty\}\to\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{\infty\}\times \mathbb{A}^2$$
in the category of sheaves over the smooth Nisnevich site is represented by an affine scheme but I'm not quite sure why is that true.

I know that the category of affine schemes has pushouts but these are in general not preserved in the category of schemes (see for example [this article by Karl Schwede](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~kschwede/SchemeWithoutPoints.pdf)). Even more, Yoneda embedding usually destroys colimits even though some can be recovered after sheafification, like for a cartesian and cocartesian square of open embeddings.

Therefore, a more general question would be: is there some partial result of the form "take a pushout square in the category of affine scheme satisfying some properties, then it stays a pushout square in the category of Nisnevich sheaves" that contains the previous example as a particular case?

Thank you very much for any possible help.